# Minecraft server closes after closing remote connection on headless Rpi4B 2GB

Tags: pi-4, headless

I had a spare pi lying about, a model 4b with 2GB ram, and recently I had been playing alot of Minecraft games with my freinds over lan from my pc but realised I could setup a server off my pi. But after setup whilst my freind was playing on it I decided to close the ssh connection I used for the setup ,I run my pi in headless mode with Raspbian lite, but was oblivious to the fact that after I closed the connection the server also closed, I only realised when my freind asked me why was the server down.

I cannot keep the ssh connection open as after some time it gets a broken pipe error, I could prevent this by entering some random command like `ls` to keep it alive but I'm not always there to hold its handbut if I was realy I was thinking to just set it up and leave it there to do what a minecraft server does. I have tried to start the server with the `&` suffix but it suspends itself early in the servers startup, however i had more succes using the `nohup` command which workswell but doesnt allow me to give input to the server which would be desireable. I have no clue how to achieve this and have been hitting my head on the table over this, any help would be great.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the ssh does not run things in the background when you run a normal command. One way to do this is to use systemd/systemctl to create a background service that will run your server. Here is a guide on how to set up a service (https://domoticproject.com/creating-raspberry-pi-service/).You can also set this up to

Note: if you're connecting your service to bash/.sh file you need this string at the top of your file `#/bin/bash`

Also, if you want to view the logs of your service you can run `journalctl -e -f -u <your service name>.service`

If you want a maybe slightly simpler way to do this, here's an article specifically for ssh connections: https://www.tecmint.com/keep-remote-ssh-sessions-running-after-disconnection/